# What are the correct set of DLLs and placement for SSL support in mIRC on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dll, mirc, openssl

I am using mIRC 6.35 on a fresh install of Windows 7 64-bit. No matter what versions of the OpenSSL DLLs I use, nor where I place them, I cannot get mIRC to work with SSL; I get the "ssl not supported" error.

The recommended DLLs on mIRC's help page (/ssl.html on the mIRC site) do not work no matter if I put them in the mIRC Program Files folder or anywhere else.  Same with the DLLs from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html which also require Visual C++ runtimes.

I am unsure if I need the 32bit DLLs (because mIRC itself is 32 bit), or the 64-bit DLLs, nor where to correctly place them. (Perhaps I currently have a case of incorrect DLLs in a path I am not aware of overriding the other placements...)

Does ANYONE have any tips for 'debugging' this, or do they themselves have it working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I used the '[Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0c Light](http://www.slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_0c.exe)' installer from slproweb.com today. I installed OpenSSL to my %ProgramFiles(x86)% folder (=> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL) and the OpenSSL DLLs to the Windows system folder.

Everything works fine ...